# jQuery convert date to a format and add timestamp

Tags: jquery

I have the following date,how can i convert it the following into the required date format using jQuery

```
startdate="30/7/2013"

required format = "Jul 30, 2013 00:00:00"
```

i tried

```
 var mydate = new Date(d);
 Wed Jul 30 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Comment: What have you tried? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date. This is a JavaScript problem, not jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

[JQuery dateFormat plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

u can also use jQueryUI datepicker

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat
then
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate
then
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat
and then
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f4YWr/1)

```
var month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

function fomat_date(d) {
    var date1 = d.split("/");
    var date_format = month[date1[1] - 1] + ' ' + date1[0] + ', ' + date1[2]+' '+'00:00:00';
    console.log(date_format);
}

fomat_date('30/7/2013'); //usage  output --> Jul 30, 2013 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/) will be the right javascript date library for parsing, validating, manipulating, and formatting dates.